# How to run multiple python based slurm jobs together in HPC

Tags: python, parallel-processing, slurm, hpc, multiple-processes

I need to submit 100 slurm jobs they all perform the same computing but with a slight change (the only difference is the year; all files have different years). Is there a way to submit them together without writing slurm file and running separately?

For example, I have 100 python files with the name: `process1.py`,  `process2.py`,  `process3.py`, ... and so on. I am looking for a way I can assign the hpc resources for all of them together, something like the below-

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -n 2
#SBATCH -p main
#SBATCH --qos main 
#SBATCH -N 1                             
#SBATCH -J name
.
.
. #other SBATCH commands
.
.
python process1.py
python process2.py
python process3.py
python process4.py....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking to submit a separate job for each Python file or have all 100 files run concurrently as part of the same job?

You can always create a loop and run a Python file inside the loop:

```
for ((i = 1; i <= 100; i++)); do
    curr_file = "process$i.py"
    python curr_file
```

If you want to run the files in parallel and your system supports that, you can also use a slurm job array. Here's what that argument looks like:

```
#SBATCH --array=1-2 # where 2 is maximum job allocation
```

Comment: I am looking to run them all parallelly, not one by one, like one starts after completion of the previous one. So what do I write in `array=1-2` if I want to run 100 of them? And how do I define all python filenames in the sbatch file?

Comment: Thanks, I was able to run using the array, with the help of this article- https://rcpedia.stanford.edu/topicGuides/jobArrayPythonExample.html

Comment: Let me clarify some of the language--it sounds like you want to run them consecutively, one after the other? That's different than running them in parallel.

Comment: Not consecutively, I want to run them all parallel with a slight change in the script